# how to conditional change gem sources when develop and build project

Tags: ruby

Now I want in develop in local machine using gem source:

```
source "https://gems.ruby-china.com"
```

when building in github actions using gem source:

```
source "https://rubygems.org/"
```

what should I do using conditaional gem sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an environment variable to determine which domain to use.

```rb
domain = ENV['RUBY_GEMS_CHINA'] ? 'https://gems.ruby-china.com' : 'https://rubygems.org'
source domain
```

You can then use `RUBY_GEMS_CHINA=1 bundle` locally to install the dependencies from [Ruby Gems China](https://gems.ruby-china.com).